# Tensorflow: how to make sure all samples in each batch are with the same label?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-processing

I wonder whether there are some ways to apply constraints on the batches to generate in Tensorflow. For example, let's say we are training a CNN on a huge dataset to do image classification. Is it possible to force Tensorflow to generate batches where all samples are with the same class? Like, one batch of images all tagged with "Apple", the other one where samples all tagged with "Orange".

The reason I ask this question is I want to do some experiments to see how different levels of shuffling influence the final trained models. It's common practice to do sample-level shuffling for CNN training, and everybody is doing it. I just want to check it myself, thus obtaining a more vivid and first-hand knowledge about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dataset.filter()` can be used:

```
labels = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10000))
data = np.random.uniform(size=(10000, 5))

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels))
ds = ds.filter(lambda data, labels: tf.equal(labels, 1)) #comment this line out for unfiltered case
ds = ds.batch(5)
iterator = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
vals = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(5):
        py_data, py_labels = sess.run(vals)
        print(py_labels)
```

with `ds.filter()`:

```
 > [1 1 1 1 1]
   [1 1 1 1 1]
   [1 1 1 1 1]
   [1 1 1 1 1]
   [1 1 1 1 1]
```

without `ds.filter()`:

```
  > [8 0 7 6 3]
    [2 4 7 6 1]
    [1 8 5 5 5]
    [7 1 7 4 0]
    [7 1 8 0 0]
```

**Edit. The following code shows how to use a feedable iterator to perform batch label selection on the fly. See "[Creating an iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)"**

```
labels = ['Apple'] * 100 + ['Orange'] * 100
data = list(range(200))
random.shuffle(labels)

batch_size = 4

ds_apple = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels)).filter(
  lambda data, label: tf.equal(label, 'Apple')).batch(batch_size)
ds_orange = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, labels)).filter(
  lambda data, label: tf.equal(label, 'Orange')).batch(batch_size)

handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
  handle, ds_apple.output_types, ds_apple.output_shapes)
batch = iterator.get_next()

apple_iterator = ds_apple.make_one_shot_iterator()
orange_iterator = ds_orange.make_one_shot_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  apple_handle = sess.run(apple_iterator.string_handle())
  orange_handle = sess.run(orange_iterator.string_handle())

  # loop and switch back and forth between apples and oranges
  for _ in range(3):
    feed_dict = {handle: apple_handle}
    print(sess.run(batch, feed_dict=feed_dict))
    feed_dict = {handle: orange_handle}
    print(sess.run(batch, feed_dict=feed_dict))
```

Typical output for this is as follows. Note that the `data` values increase monotonically across Apple and Orange batches showing that the iterators are not resetting.

```
> (array([2, 3, 6, 7], dtype=int32), array([b'Apple', b'Apple', b'Apple', b'Apple'], dtype=object))
  (array([0, 1, 4, 5], dtype=int32), array([b'Orange', b'Orange', b'Orange', b'Orange'], dtype=object))
  (array([ 9, 13, 15, 19], dtype=int32), array([b'Apple', b'Apple', b'Apple', b'Apple'], dtype=object))
  (array([ 8, 10, 11, 12], dtype=int32), array([b'Orange', b'Orange', b'Orange', b'Orange'], dtype=object))
  (array([21, 22, 23, 25], dtype=int32), array([b'Apple', b'Apple', b'Apple', b'Apple'], dtype=object))
  (array([14, 16, 17, 18], dtype=int32), array([b'Orange', b'Orange', b'Orange', b'Orange'], dtype=object))
```

Comment: In your example shown above, the filter is applied on each sample. I wonder can the filter be applied on each batch? I need the samples in each batch are with the same labels (all with 1, all with 2, all with 3,, etc), not necessarily only 1. If no one single batch contains two samples with different labels, it's okay. In summary: I want to filter batches containing samples with different labels. Or I want to force Tensorflow to generate batches obeying this rule.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. The condition statement above can be changed to `tf.equal(labels, target)` where `target` can be set elsewhere to whatever label you want. If the filter is applied to the batch then it would seem batch sizes will change between steps.

Comment: Just to make myself fully understood: a batch (4-samples) like this [Apple, Apple, Apple, Apple] or like this [Orange, Orange, Orange, Orange] are both okay. I only want the label of all samples are the same in each batch, no extra constraint or requirement about the label. So you suggested, that I dynamically set "target" to choose "Apple" or "Orange" on the fly during training?

Comment: OK, I edited my answer to show how to filter batches dynamically using a feedable iterator. I never used one before so it was good experience for me. Hope it gives you what you need.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want.